# Download BAIR-trained Caffe Model Using Script

Tags: docker, command-line, deep-learning, caffe, pycaffe

I am trying to download via command line the Caffe implementation of AlexNet (found here: https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/tree/master/models/bvlc_alexnet) using the following script:

```
python /scripts/download_model_binary.py /models/bvlc_reference_caffenet/
```

but I get the error:

```
download_model_binary.py: error: argument dirname: Must be valid Caffe model directory with a correct readme.md
```

I cannot download the file manually or using wget because of some permissions issues/I am working in a docker container.

How can I download using the script?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are giving **absolute** path to the model folder (starting with '/') rather than **relative** path.
Why don't you try

```
download_model_binary.py models/bvlc_reference_caffenet
```

BTW, this should download AlexNet and not GoogLeNet.

Comment: When I run `python /caffe/caffe/scripts/download_model_binary.py models/bvlc_alexnet` I get the same error.

Comment: what is your "current working directory"? you need to run this script.from your CAFFE_ROOT folder

Comment: how about `python /caffe/caffe/scripts/download_model_binary.py /caffe/caffe/models/bvlc_reference_caffenet` ?